# How to represent integer in hex using Gson?

Tags: java, json, hex, gson

I have a List of objects, let's say:

```
List<Timestamp>
```

Each "Timestamp" object includes other objects, in particular it has a "Tag" object.

```
class Timestamp {
    String time;
    ...
    Tag tag;
    ...
}
```

Now, every Tag object is identified by an ID of type "Integer".

```
class Tag {
    Integer id;
    ...
}
```

For a few reasons, I have to write the JSON representation of the whole timestamp list into a file by using the Gson library. In some cases I need the decimal representation of the ID of each Tag, while in other cases I need IDs in hexadecimal format.

How can I "switch" between the two formats? Consider that to write the whole list of Timestamp objects I use the following instruction:

```
ps.println(gson.toJson(timestamps));
```

and I can't add other fields/types/objects in the Tag class because the JSON representation would be different.

Comment: This seems like a non-issue if I understand you correctly? If when converting to JSON you want the `id` to be an integer, it will be. So ... when you're not converting it to JSON and need the hexadecimal (`String`) representation, simply convert `id` to that.

Comment: The issue is that I have a log file where IDs can be integer or hexadecimal numbers. In my java code I have classes to associate my parsed objects. One of this class is Tag where, for some reasons, id has to be an integer. But, what happens when the log file has IDs in hexadecimal format? I can parse them to integer (according to my Tag class), but I need to export them back to hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer:

1. write a custom gson serializer for the Tag class.
2. Add a flag variable to Tag that indicates when to output the id in hex and when to toutput the id in decimal.
3. Create a toString() method on the Tag class that pays attention to the newly added flag.

Custom Serializer (variation from the gson doc example)

```
private class TagSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Tag>
{
  public JsonElement serialize(Tag src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
  {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
  }
}
```

Register the custom serializer

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(Tag.class, new TagSerializer());
```

Tag Updates

```
boolean displayIdInHex = false;

public void setDisplayIdInDecimal()
{
  displayIdInHex = false;
}

public void setDisplayIdInHex()
{
  displayIdInHex = true;
}

public String toString()
{
  ... stuff ...
  if (displayIdInHex)
  {
    ... output id in hex.
  }
  else
  {
    ... output id in decimal.
  }
}
```

TimeStamp Updates
    public void setDisplayIdInDecimal()
    {
      tag.setDisplayIdInDecimal();
    }

```
public void setDisplayIdInHex()
{
  tag.setDisplayIdInHex();
}
```

Comment: the reuslt will be a `String` in your json Object like {id:"32A44C"}

Answer (score 1):

An `Integer` itself has no format it is just a number.
If you want to have it in hex-format, you have to use a `String` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: Yes I know, but unfortunately I can't use the String. I need the Integer for the JSON representation, excepting in case of HEX IDs.

Comment: If you can't use a `String` then you can't use hexadecimal. Hexadecimal *is* a string. There is no other way to represent it. (See: http://www.json.org/ search page for "hexadecimal").

Comment: I mean, I can't use String directly in my Tag class, but if there's a way to change my ID from Integer to a String during the writing process, it could be fine.

Comment: See the code from DwB you can also add an internal logic fore `displayIdInHex` instead of the two setter functions. Be careful, whoever has to recieve the json have to handle also both types `Number` and `String` for the field `Id`